# iOS Remove Old Notification from Tray and Show New Received Notification

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

we are using `firebase` for sending `push notification`, is it possible to remove `duplicate notification` from notification tray. In notification JSON we are sending params named `uid`, if same `uid` is already available in old notification means we need to remove old notification from notification center and show new notification. How it is possible? or give me some better solution to fix it.

Comment: Try removing duplicate notifications from Service Extension. When you receive any notification, check for its ID and remove it from the Notification centre and display the new one. And please make sure to add "content-available" to "1" in your notification payload.

Comment: @ManishKumar is it possible for you to share some sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)deleteNotificationWithId:(NSString*)Id
    { 
    NSString *myIDToCancel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Id];
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

            if([currSysVer floatValue] >= 10)
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

                [center getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest *> * _Nonnull requests) {

                    NSMutableArray *strArrayToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                    for (UNNotificationRequest *request in requests){

                        if([myIDToCancel isEqualToString:[request.content.userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"]])
                        {
                            [strArrayToDelete addObject:request.identifier];
                        }
                    }

                    if(strArrayToDelete.count >0)
                    {
                        [center removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:strArrayToDelete];
                    }

                }];
            }
            else
            {

                NSString *myIDToCancel = Id;

                UILocalNotification *notificationToCancel=nil;

                for(UILocalNotification *aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])
                {
                    if([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:myIDToCancel])
                    {
                        notificationToCancel=aNotif;

                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationToCancel];

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
         }

    }
```

Comment: can you tell me from where I want to call this function?. I tried to call it from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but its not working

Comment: you can call this function in your root view controller

Comment: but actually what I need to do is I want to clear previously received notifications in `Notification Center` when new notification received with same `ID`

Comment: you should have an unique id for every notification, Refer this Link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649634-identifier?language=objc